# Regex for different parts of line

Tags: regex, for-loop, line

There data samples where I need find right regex to fit all samples

```
1) NG277 5.5x13/4x100 D73.1 ET38 BKF = 5.5x13/4x100 D73.1 ET38
2) MC7/B 7x17/5x114.3 D70.6 ET54 Silver = 7x17/5x114.3 D70.6 ET54
3) S 7 Modify 7.5x18/5x112 D73 ET42 Silver = 7.5x18/5x112 D73 ET42
4) MK-Course Mod.08 7.5x18/5x100 D56.1 ET55
5) Fever-5R 8x18/5x120 D74.1 ET15 Black Mirror
6) R6162 9x20/5x108 D67.1 ET40 S
7) 35 Anniversary 8x18/5x120 ET34 Black
8) Lounge 8 & 10 8x18/5x110 D75 ET38 Black
9) RSL 5068TL 8.5x18/5x112 D71.6 ET40 MLB
10 Килиманджаро-5-оригинал 6x15/5x114.3 D67.1 ET52.5
11) RK L31F 6x15/4x100 D54.1 ET48 S
12 X-113 7x17/5x115 D70.1 ET41 BK/FP
```

I need remove everything until values like 5x13 or 7.5x13 and everything after values like ET38 ET55.
Here is me regex `^[-+!\sА-яа-яA-zA-Z]*|[-\sА-яа-яA-zA-Z]*$` but it's not working right. I hope somebody can help.

Comment: what did you want to get? give the sample for some line of expected value

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I need Russian and English.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match your lines and create a capture group for the part you want to retain:

```
^.*?([\d.]+\s*(x|х)\s*[\d.]+\s*\/.*ET-?\d+).*$
                 ^ note that this x is actually unicode code point U+0445
                                               (CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EF)
```

Simply enter this as your search term and enter the first capture group (usually indicated as \1) as your replacement.

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/xW8lG7

In notepad++ simply use search->replace. Enable regex, enter the regex and replace with $1.

Comment: it's very strange but this expression working only on web site. I tried replace all match in notepad and it's removed all data.

Comment: I am sorry it work but now well enough.
Data sample like this: 
1) София 5.5x13/4x98 ET35 2) Палладика 7x16/5x139.7 D98 ET5 Алмаз черный 3) 35TH Anniversary 8x18/5x108 ET27 Black 4)Уран 6x14/4x108 ET37

Comment: it's cut too many values I need 35TH Anniversary 8x18/5x108 ET27 Black = 8x18/5x108 ET27

Comment: Now everything works perfect except thous values: H-323 8x15/6x139.7 H-323 8x15/6x139.7 D110.5 ET-28 HS D/P
H-526 7x15/6x139.7 D110.5 ET-13 HS
LS182 10x15/5x139.7 D108.5 ET-40 BKF
Талисман-Мега 7х16/5x139.7 D95.3 ET35 блэк платинум
P0457 8.5 x 20/5x100 D73.1 ET35 Chrome
7100 7x16/6x139.7 D112.2 ET-15 Silver

Comment: I am sorry ask you you many questions, but looks like you expert :)

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++, you can do:

```
search: ^.+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?x\d+(?:\.\d+)?.+?ET\d+).+?$
replace with: $1
```